# scope checkbox value not passed on to directive?

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, validation

This is a directive which does a simple validation with a regex. For some reason I have issues passing on the checkbox value which is outside the directive. I am trying to read the checkbox value which is called scope.validationEnabled in my directive called checkEmailOnBlur:

```
app.directive('checkEmailOnBlur', function() {
  var ABN_REGX = /^(\d *?){3}$/;
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {

      if (scope.validationEnabled) {

        if (attr.type === 'radio' || attr.type === 'checkbox') return;
        elm.unbind('input').unbind('keydown').unbind('change');

        elm.bind('blur', function() {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            if (ABN_REGX.test(elm.val())) {
              ctrl.$setValidity('abns', true);
              console.log('valid abn');
              scope.acn = "1010101";
              scope.displayName = "display name";
              scope.otherName = "otherName";
              scope.description = "desc";

            } else {
              ctrl.$setValidity('abns', false);
              console.log('not valid abn');
              scope.acn = "";
              scope.displayName = "";
              scope.otherName = "";
              scope.description = ""
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }
  };
```

Question: at the moment the for scope.validationEnabled is not set to TRUE when I check the checkbox. How can I pass on the checkbox value?
Here is a plnkr reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/O69SP2sB5NZcPirImhrh?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the link function is executed `scope.validationEnabled` will in this case be `undefined` which is `falsy`. The link function will not attach the event listener to `blur`.

The link function will not run again until the next time the HTML is compiled, so it will not matter if you check the box.

Move the `if` into the event listener function:

```
elm.bind('blur', function() {

  if (!scope.validationEnabled) return;

  // Code
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/qS5YP546qX8I9QwIwupz?p=preview